# Cannot locate symbol referenced by prebuilt shared library

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I cannot solve this issue even though there are so many similar questions over here, so I decided to post my own problem.
A recap:

1. I compiled my library as a prebuilt shared library (`.so`) with `android-cmake` since I was already using cmake for my library. In the cmake, I used `gnustl_shared` in the `ANDROID_STL` option (I tried also with `stlport_shared` but no luck).
2. I used the native `ndk-build` compiler. This is my `Android.mk` file:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   ### include the lib as a prebuilt lib ###
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE            := libOS
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := libOS.so
   LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /home/Dev/libOS/include \
                              /home/Dev/libOS/include/yos/os \
                              /home/Dev/yos/build-arm/generated_include

   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

   ### build your ndk lib ###
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE := hello
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gnustl_shared libOS

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

   and this is my `Application.mk`:

   ```
   APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
   APP_STL := gnustl_shared
   APP_MODULES := libOS hello
   APP_PLATFORM := android-19
   ```
3. The application compiles properly, and everything is fine. In the moment in which I call the native function, it goes nuts, by throwing at me the following:

   ```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz" referenced by "libOS.so"...
   ```

Further, here is a snippet of my `MainActivity.java`:

```
static{
    // System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
    System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
    System.loadLibrary("libOS");
    System.loadLibrary("hello");
}

public native String hello();
```

Since I do not really understand what to do, I would really love any help! I also tried with similar questions such as this one [android ndk UnsatisfiedLinkError when using a prebuilt shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299802/android-ndk-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-a-prebuilt-shared-library) but no luck for now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I am using android studio. But I disabled the gradle compilation (at least I think I disabled it) by adding the following to the `build.gradle`: `sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = [] // disable automatic ndk-build call, which ignore our Android.mk
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'` I also added some more commands I've found online in order for the IDE to directly use `ndk-build`

Comment: Because as far I understood it was not working with my setup, i.e. a set of prebuilt shared libraries for which I had to define a custom `Android.mk`. Is that wrong?

Comment: Don't know about Android, but usually the "throw" functions are in libc++. You have to either link your library with that or load it in advance too (or if it doesn't exist on Android, find out what the equivalent is).

Comment: Right now, I am loading and linking with `gnustl_shared`. I already tried with `stlport_shared` library with no luck. Do you think it is worth trying with `c++_shared`? I do not really understand the differences between `stl` and `libc++` honestly.

Comment: Can you do an `ldd` on libgnustl_shared.so and see if it shows any dependencies? If yes, try to add them to your code. I know STL only as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library. I assume in Android it's the same. It doesn't contain the implementation of C++ language features like "throw". These are ususally in some lib*c++*.so